# Write a Python function squareprime(l)

Tags: python-3.x

Write a Python function squareprime(l) that takes a non-empty list of integers and returns True if the elements of l alternate between perfect squares and prime numbers, and returns False otherwise. Note that the alternating sequence of squares and primes may begin with a square or with a prime.

Here are some examples to show how your function should work.

```
>>> primesquare([4])
True

>>> primesquare([4,5,16,101,64])
True

>>> primesquare([5,16,101,36,27])
False
```

Comment: Please see this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to put forward your question...

Answer (score 1):

1. Function prime_checker checks if a number is prime or not.
2. Function is_square checks if a number is prefect_square or not.
3. If the number at index 0 is square, then the chain is like [square, prime, square...]
4. else the sequence goes like [prime, square, prime, square..]
5. If the input sequence is not either of the two, then it is not a valid sequence and it will return False.

   ```
   import math

   def prime_checker(num): 
      flag = True
      if num == 2:
          return True
      elif num < 2:
          return False
      else:
          for i in range(2, int(num/2)):
              if num % i  == 0:
                  flag = False
                  break
      return flag

   def is_square(integer):
       if integer == 0:
           return false
       root = math.sqrt(integer)
       if int(root + 0.5) ** 2 == integer: 
           return True
       return False`

   def primesquare(list_nums):
      if len(list_nums) == 0:
          return False
      if len(list_nums) == 1:
          if (is_square(list_nums[0]) or prime_checker(list_nums[0])):
              return True
          else:
              return False
      else:
          flag = True
          if is_square(list_nums[0]):
              check_for = 'prime'
          elif prime_checker(list_nums[0]):
              check_for = 'square'
          else:
              return False
          for i in range(1,len(list_nums)):
              if (check_for == 'prime' and prime_checker(list_nums[i])):
                  check_for = 'square'
              elif (check_for == 'square' and is_square(list_nums[i])):
                  check_for = 'prime'
              else:
                  flag = False
                  break     
          if flag:
              return True
          else:
              return False
   ```

**Update:**
As the element at the 0th index has already been checked, we are not concerned about that number anymore. Hence, if the 0th element is a prime number, then the sequence will be [prime, square, prime, square,...].
If it is a perfect square, then the sequence will be [square, prime, square, prime...].

If it is neither of the two, then it is not a valid sequence and hence, `false` is returned.

Now, if the first number was either of the two, and the length of the list is greater than 1, then we will iterate over the remaining elements and check if they are similar to what we expected, but changing the value of `check_for` variable.

If the value of `check_for` is `prime` and the value that we encountered is also prime, then we know that the next number of the sequence should be a square number for the sequence to be a valid sequence. The similar thing happens when a square number is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import sqrt
def square(n):
    if(sqrt(n) % 1 == 0):
        return True
    else:
        return False
def isprime(n):
    if (n == 1):
        return(False)
    for i in range(2,int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n%i==0:
            return False
    return True
def squareprime(l):
    s=l[0]
    if(isprime(s)):
        for i in range(0,len(l),2):
            if(isprime(l[i])==False):
                return False
        for i in range(1,len(l),2):
            if(square(l[i])==False):
                return False
        return True
    elif(square(s)):
        for i in range(0,len(l),2):
            if(square(l[i])==False):
                return False
        for i in range(1,len(l),2):
            if(isprime(l[i])==False):
                return False
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import sqrt
def square(n):
    if(sqrt(n) % 1 == 0):
        return True
    else:
        return False
def isprime(n):
    for i in range(2,int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n%i==0:
            return False
    return True
def primesquare(list_nums):
   if len(list_nums) == 0:
       return False
   if len(list_nums) == 1:
       if (square(list_nums[0]) or isprime(list_nums[0])):
           return True
       else:
           return False
   else:
       flag = True
       if square(list_nums[0]):
           check_for = 'prime'
       elif isprime(list_nums[0]):
           check_for = 'square'
       else:
           return False
       for i in range(1,len(list_nums)):
           if (check_for == 'prime' and isprime(list_nums[i])):
               check_for = 'square'
           elif (check_for == 'square' and square(list_nums[i])):
               check_for = 'prime'
           else:
               flag = False
               break     
       if flag:
           return True
       else:
           return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import sqrt 
def isprime(n):
    for i in range(2,int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n%i==0:
            return False
    return True

def primesquare(l):
    flag=0
    if len(l)==1:
        n=l[0]
        if(sqrt(n)%1==0):
            return True
    else:
        for i in range(0,len(l)):
            if(sqrt(l[i])%1==0):
                if(i==0):
                    if(isprime(l[i+1])==True):
                        flag=1
                    else:
                        if(isprime(l[i-1])==True):
                            if(isprime[i+1]==True):
                                flag=1
                            else:
                                flag=0
                        else:
                            flag=0

    if(flag==0):
        return False
    else:
        return True
```